# What should be the right behavior for back button when replace a Fragment with itself

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 Fragments (Main, About and Help)
I have a menu with 3 option ("Show Main Fragment", "Show About Fragment "and "Show Help Fragment")

When i select one of the 3 menu options, I do:

```
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {

        case 1:
            fragment = new MainFragment();
            break;              
        case 3:
            fragment = new HelpFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    ft.commit();
```

If I add 2, 3 or more diferent fragments, it works ok.

But if I add the same fragment consecutively, when I click on back button, it show me the same fragment, not the previously added.

Let me explain better.

1. Click "Show About Fragment"
2. AboutFragment is added to the MainLayout
3. AboutFragment is Showed on screen
4. Click "Show Main Fragment"
5. MainFragment is added to the MainLayout
6. MainFragment is Showed on screen
7. Click "Show Main Fragment" (again)
8. MainFragment is added to the MainLayout (again)
9. MainFragment is Showed on screen (again)
10. Click back button
11. MainFragment is Showed on screen !!

When I click on back button (Step 10), I want to show AboutFragment.
But it show me again the MainFragment. It is that right? or I doing something wrong?
I need to made a popBackStack() call before?

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: it is because you always invoke ft.addToBackStack(null); just skipp it in case you don't want to have it on backStack

Comment: Why would you want the Help or About fragments added to the backstack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your steps you add the `MainFragment`twice so of course its going to show again after you hit the back button in step 10, there is still another `MainFragment` in the back stack.

If you dont want to show the MainFragment again the dont add the `ManiFragment` to the backstack a second time, then you will end up back at the `AboutFragment`

Comment: Yes I supposed that. I just want to confirm. I solved checking if the previous fragment it is the same, if is that the situation, I made a call to popBackStack() before add the second, so if the user add the same fragment consecutively works right. thanks for the answers